# How can I pass additional args in as_view in Django REST framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my urls I want to pass additional args like this

```
MyListView.as_view(extra="test")
```

But when I do that then I get error that I can only pass those attributes which are defined in class.

I tried this

```
class MyListView(APIView):
    def as_view(self, extra=None, **kwargs):
        self.extra=kwargs.pop('extra', None)
        super(MyListView, self).as_view(**kwargs)
```

Then I get

```
unbound method as_view() must be called with MyListView instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword arguments to the `MyListView.as_view()` call are passed to the `__init__` method each time a view instance is needed (e.g. when handling a request); you can override that method to capture the `extra` keyword:

```
class MyListView(APIView):
    def __init__(self, extra=None, **kwargs):
        self.extra = extra
        super(MyListView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

The [`as_view()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view) must be a classmethod; it is not called on an instance of the view:

```
class MyListView(APIView):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, extra=None, **kwargs):
        cls.extra = extra
        return super(MyListView, cls).as_view(**kwargs)
```

The `extra` keyword argument is explicitly named so it'll never be found in the `kwargs` catch-all. You also want to *return* the result of the `super()` call.

Note that the `extra` attribute is then also shared between all instances of the view! You may as well set it directly on the view class:

```
class MyListView(APIView):
    extra = 'test'
```

Since `as_view()` must produce an instance, you can add the attribute on the return value of the `super()` call before passing it on:

```
class MyListView(APIView):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, extra=None, **kwargs):
        view = super(MyListView, cls).as_view(**kwargs)
        view.extra = extra
        return view
```

but then overriding the `__init__` is achieving the same result and easier to follow for future maintainers.