# The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `builtins.str`

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

Please help me guys to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Here, if phone number exists it shows me that it's exists, otherwise throws me an error like:
`AssertionError at /validate_phone/

The request argument must be an instance of django.http.HttpRequest, not builtins.str.
`

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class ValidatePhoneSendOTP(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_number = request.data.get('phone')  

        if phone_number:
            phone = str(phone_number)
            user = UserModel.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
            if user.exists():
                return Response({
                    'status': False,
                    'detail': 'Phone number already exists'
                })
            else:
                key = send_otp(phone)
                if key:
                    old = PhoneOTP.objects.filter(phone__iexact=phone)
                    if old.exists():
                        old = old.first()
                        count = old.count()
                        if count > 10:
                            return Response({
                                'status': False,
                                'detail': "Sending otp error. Limit exceeded. Please contact customer support."
                            })
                        old.count = count + 1
                        old.save()
                        print("count increase", count)
                        return Response({
                            'status': True,
                            'detail': "OTP sent successfully."
                        })
                    else:
                        PhoneOTP.objects.create(
                            phone=phone,
                            otp=key,
                        )
                        return Response({
                            'status': True,
                            'detail': 'OTP sent successfully'
                        })
```

Comment: Always post the full error traceback!

Comment: Alright I got you

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011495/how-can-i-pass-additional-args-in-as-view-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are decorating the class with `@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))` and this generates some string and it is goes through your API class that expects `django.http.HttpRequest`

the usage of permission on `APIView` is:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

from [drf documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

Answer (score 1):

If you could add all code referenced above that would help. This has happened to me when trying to do async tasks in Django